# Prove that f(x)=C1sinx +C2cosx for constant C1 and C2...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

It's given that f is differentiable twice and that $f''+f=0$ I have to show that $f(x)=C_1\sin(x) +C_2\cos(x)$ for constant $C_1$ and $C_2$.
There is also a hint: using the given data, prove that $[(f')^2+f^2]'=0$ which proves that $(f')^2+f^2$ is a constant function. Now conclude that if $f'(0)=f(0)=0$ then $f$ is identically zero. Now, how can you conclude the claim aforementioned?

I have managed to prove that the hint is true. But I can't seem to understand; how can I show that a function that meats those criteria is necessarily of the mentioned form? I could use some help...

Comment: If you are just trying to solve $f'' + f = 0$, try an ansatz $f = e^{\lambda x}$ in the equation and see what comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $f''(x)+f(x)=0$, then let $g(x)=f(x)+a\sin x+b\cos x$.  It follows that $g''(x)+g(x)=0$.  Try to find a $g(x)$ with $g(0)=g'(0)=0$.

Comment: Awesome! 
Or should I say: Thank you very much for your perspicuous reply :) 
I heard it's not conventional here to use the lexica that is beneath a courtroom. lol

Answer (score 1):

Mutiply the ode by $f'$ yeilds
$$
f''f' + ff' = 0
$$
Now using the fact
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}f'^2 = 2f'f''
$$
(Prove it for yourself) and
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}f^2 = 2ff'
$$ 
(Prove this also) can you see where the form comes from?

Comment: Is \dfrac{d}{dx}f^2 = 2ff' the derivative of f^2? f is differentiable twice...

Comment: yes, on both counts.